# The following program to convert infix expression to postfix does not produce correct result?

Tags: c++, stack

The following program is used to convert the infix expression to postfix, But it produces the input string as output that is the program is not giving postfix expression as output.
Please explain what is wrong with the code.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct stack{
    int top;
    unsigned capacity;
    char *arr;
};

void push(struct stack * stk,char data){
    if(stk->top != stk->capacity-1) 
        stk->arr[++stk->top]=data;
}

char pop(struct stack* stk){
    if(stk->top!= -1){
        char c = stk->arr[stk->top];
        stk->top--;
        return c;
    }
}
int priority(char c){
    switch(c){
    case '+': return 1;
    case '-': return 1;
    case '*': return 2;
    case '/': return 2;
    case '^': return 3;
    }
}

void intopostfix(char * ch){
    struct stack *stk = (struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    stk->top=-1;
    stk->capacity = strlen(ch);  
    if(!stk){cout<<"stack not created";}
    int i,k;
    for(i=0,k=-1; ch[i] ; ++i){
        if((ch[i]>='a' && ch[i]<='z')||(ch[i]>='A' && ch[i]<='Z') ){
            ch[++k]=ch[i];
        }
        else if(ch[i]=='('){
            push(stk,ch[i]);
        }
        else if(ch[i]==')'){
            while((stk->top!=-1)&& (ch[i]!='('))
            {
                ch[++k]=pop(stk);
                //k++;
            }
        }
        else{
            while((stk->top!=-1)&&(priority(ch[i])<=priority(stk->arr[stk->top]))){
                ch[++k]=pop(stk);

            }
            push(stk,ch[i]);
        }
        while(stk->top!=-1){
            ch[++k]=pop(stk);

            //k++;
        }

    }
       for(i=0;ch[i]!='\0';i++)
       cout<<ch[i];

}
int main(){
    clrscr();
    char exp[]="a+b*(c^d-e)^(f+g*h)-i";
    intopostfix(exp);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The program outputs the same string as output ie
     a+b*(c^d-e)^(f+g*h)-i

Comment: Did you try using a debugger? Single step through your program and you will see the issue in no time.

Comment: Whichever tutorial teaches the use of "iostream.h" or "conio.h" shouldn't be worth your time. Compilers that still accept these are probably also horribly outdated. There are other things wrong with your code as well, most of which shouldn't occur if you learned from a good source, check out e.g. http://www.icce.rug.nl/documents/cplusplus/.

Comment: Read some good [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/Tour.html) book (or [this](http://stroustrup.com/programming.html) ...). Use a good, C++11 or C++14 conforming compiler. Use [C++ containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/). You'll better **scrap your entire code and start again** after having learned and read many things. Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -g`). Use a recent version of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/). Consider using Linux, and a recent `gdb`debugger.

Comment: Learn more about [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques, perhaps implementing some [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). You really should dump your code in the trash bin and start again after having spent several hours or days on reading.

Answer (score 0):

The following Changes are required

1. The last while statement needs to be moved outside of for loop. This needs to be done after processing all tokens. See the algorithm here http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/BasicDS/InfixPrefixandPostfixExpressions.html

   2. Output should be written to a separate variable
   3. A default case needs to be added to switch statement

   default : return 0;

   4. Memory needs to allocated to stack

   stk->arr = (char *)malloc(500);

Other minor changes are also required.

Here are the modified parts of the code

```
int priority(char c){
    switch(c){
    case '+': return 1;
    case '-': return 1;
    case '*': return 2;
    case '/': return 2;
    case '^': return 3;
    default : return 0;
    }
}


void intopostfix(char * ch){
    struct stack *stk = (struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
//struct stack *stk = (struct stack*)malloc(500);
    stk->arr = (char *)malloc(500);
    stk->top=-1;
    stk->capacity = strlen(ch);
    char postFixStr [500];
    if(!stk){cout<<"stack not created";}
    int i,k;
    for(i=0,k=-1; ch[i] ; ++i){
        if((ch[i]>='a' && ch[i]<='z')||(ch[i]>='A' && ch[i]<='Z') ){
            postFixStr[++k]=ch[i];
        }
        else if(ch[i]=='('){
            push(stk,ch[i]);
        }
        else if(ch[i]==')'){
            while((stk->top != -1)&& (stk->arr[stk->top] != '('))
            {
                postFixStr[++k]=pop(stk);
                //k++;
            }
            pop(stk);
        }
        else{
            while((stk->top!=-1)&&(priority(ch[i])<=priority(stk->arr[stk->top]))){
                postFixStr[++k]=pop(stk);

            }
            push(stk,ch[i]);
        }
    }
    while(stk->top!=-1){
          postFixStr[++k]=pop(stk);

          //k++;
    }

      postFixStr[++k] = '\0';

       //for(i=0;ch[i]!='\0';i++)
       //cout<<ch[i];
       cout<<postFixStr << endl;

}
```

Comment: Idiomatic C++ should almost never use `malloc`. Prefer standard containers, and at least use `new` & `delete`, not `malloc` & `free`